# Javascript alert in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I need to call Javascript alert function in c# method if web service is not available. I am using as.net core and webapi for webservice.

Here is the code

```
  public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployeeByEmpNo(string empNo)
    {
        try
        {
            string Baseurl = sys_ser.getApiURL();
            EmployeeModel EmpInfo = new EmployeeModel();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                HttpResponseMessage Res = client.GetAsync("api/Values/GetEmployeeByEmpNo/" + empNo).Result;


                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var empobjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeModel>>(EmpResponse);
                    //var EmpObj = empobjList[0];

                    if (empobjList != null)
                    {
                        return empobjList;
                    }



                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //<Srcript> alert('WebService is not available' + ex.message)</>
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't confuse client-side code with server-side code. What this asks for is a **terrible** idea and fortunately ASP.NET Core does not provide any help for doing this. Just return the error message and make the AJAX call display the result

Comment: You cant do that. What you could do is to perform a check in the front-end javascript. If you are getting a null response throw an alert then.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know that but i thought there is a way i can achieve that but anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If AJAX isn't an option, you can pass a flag to tell the client to create the window:

Controller:

```
return View("Index", (object)errorDetails);
```

View:

```
@model string
<!--Your HTML-->

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(Model);
    </script>
}
```